# Performing a non '$set' update with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

The Mongoose documents note that any Model update is automatically sent using '$set':

```
var query = { name: 'borne' };
Model.update(query, { name: 'jason borne' }, options, callback)

// is sent as

Model.update(query, { $set: { name: 'jason borne' }}, options, callback)
```

But I want to perform the traditional Mongo update that, in effect, *resets* the document with the supplied values. But I can't seem to find any easy way to do this using Mongoose. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native driver `update` to get the traditional behavior:

```js
Model.collection.update.update(query, {name: 'jason borne'}, options, callback);
```

Keep in mind that none of Mongoose's schema-based type casting will be done when you do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the overwite option for it. It is mentioned in the documentation - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#update_update

[image: Overwite Option from mongoose docs]